# Python: Create Dictionary From List with [0] = Key and [1:]= Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation, python-itertools

I am using the permutations function from `itertools`, and wish to convert the returned list to a dictionary, with the first element (the original sequence) as Key and all possible combinations of this sequence as its corresponding Values.

For instance, output for 'cups' and 'pups' looks like this:

```
['cups', 'cusp', 'cpus', 'cpsu', 'csup', 'cspu', 'ucps', 'ucsp', 'upcs', 'upsc', 'uscp',
'uspc', 'pcus', 'pcsu', 'pucs', 'pusc', 'pscu', 'psuc', 'scup', 'scpu', 'sucp', 'supc', 
'spcu', 'spuc']

['pups', 'pusp', 'ppus', 'ppsu', 'psup', 'pspu', 'upps', 'upsp', 'upps', 'upsp', 'uspp', 
'uspp', 'ppus', 'ppsu', 'pups', 'pusp', 'pspu', 'psup', 'spup', 'sppu', 'supp', 'supp',  
'sppu', 'spup']
```

From this, I want:

```
{'cups': ['cusp', 'cpus', 'cpsu', 'csup'...], 'pups': ['pusp', 'ppus', 'ppsu'...]}
```

Comment: Is it me or have you answered your own question? If your list is `x`, then it's `{x[0]: x[1:]}`

Comment: I didn't answer it...but I see you have the same answer as someone else.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***[dictionary expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)***

```
data = [['cups', 'cusp', 'cpus', 'cpsu', 'csup', 'cspu',],
        ['pups', 'pusp','upsp', 'upps', 'upsp', 'uspp']]

result = {each[0]:each[1:] for each in data}           
print result
```

Yields:

```
{'pups': ['pusp', 'upsp', 'upps', 'upsp', 'uspp'], 
'cups': ['cusp', 'cpus', 'cpsu', 'csup', 'cspu']}
```

Comment: I had to  modify this slightly, but it's working.  :)  Thank you!

      intermed_dict = {perms[0]:perms[1:] for each in perms}  
      word_dict.update(intermed_dict)